# How do I select an element by it's toggled class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I have what seems to be a simple problem, but having some trouble. I want to only display an alert message once when I hit the X of my hamburger toggle menu. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I have in my codepen that I am referencing: https://codepen.io/toshvelaga/pen/wLJYKL

I have tried using the code below, but I get the alert message twice and also when clicking on the hamburger instead of just ONLY the X.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');

        $('#nav-icon3.open').click(function() {
            alert("hello");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Creating event handlers inside another event handler is a really bad practice. Every time one clicks the element with `id="nav-icon3"` a new event handler will be placed into memory. Then, upon each click of the element with `id="nav-icon3.open"` each of those handlers will execute. FWIW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the element has the `open` class in the (single) handler, and if it does, log the `hello`:

```js
$('#nav-icon3').click(function() {
  if (this.matches('.open')) {
    console.log("hello");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
/* Icon 3 */

#nav-icon3 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon3 span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3531a;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(2),
#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon3 span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon3.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-icon3">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We will add a **click** event listener to the third `span` element, which is where the X is located in this case(I assume).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span:nth-child(3)').click(function () {
        alert('X has been clicked') 
    })
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.